# Get all words between start and end charecter

Tags: java, regex

My Problem :

**Regular Expression**

[image]

I want  match this string (URL) from starting "&title=" to next "&"
But this expression (&title=.+&){1} is matching up to last "&".  (without quotes)

My Code :

```
    public static void youtubeDownloadURL(String url){

       int t=url.indexOf("&title=");
       String srtToMatch=url.substring(t,url.length());
       Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(&title=.+&){1}");
       Matcher m = p.matcher(srtToMatch);
       while(m.find()){

         System.out.println(m.group());
         break;

       }
   }
```

Comment: You may be looking for `&title=[^&]+`. The latter means `not a &` as long as possible.

Comment: Surely Java has actual URL query parameter parsing.  Is there a particular reason you're using manual regex instead?

Comment: I was trying to fetch the file name from url. And file name was after "title="

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for `&title=[^&]+`.
The latter means not a & as long as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The non-greedy `?` works fine.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(&title=.+?&){1}");
```